# How to use inter-process communication (IPC)/websocket in django with discord.py and discord-ext-ipc

Tags: python, django, discord.py, django-channels, quart

I'm currently using [`discord-ext-ipc`](https://github.com/Ext-Creators/discord-ext-ipc) as an inter-process communication (IPC) extension for discord.py and linked this with [`quart-discord`](https://github.com/jnawk/Quart-Discord). Quart is an asyncio reimplementation of Flask and can natively serve WebSockets and other asynchronous stuff.
I can so easily use a Web-Frontend as a Dashboard to interact with the discord users on a guild. Doing fun stuff like, using the discord role model for a permission model at the dashboard.

Recently I stumbled over django and got hooked up with that powerful framework. As a learning project, I wanted to port the current working project into django but I stumbled over some impasses.

### First the working example with `discord-ext-ipc` and `quart-discord`:

> bot.py

```
import logging
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, ipc
intents = discord.Intents.default()

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

TOKEN = DISCORD_TOKEN

class MyBot(commands.Bot):

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)

        self.ipc = ipc.Server(self,secret_key = IPC_SECRET_KEY)

    async def on_ready(self):
        """Called upon the READY event"""
        print("Bot is ready.")

    async def on_ipc_ready(self):
        """Called upon the IPC Server being ready"""
        print("Ipc server is ready.")

    async def on_ipc_error(self, endpoint, error):
        """Called upon an error being raised within an IPC route"""
        print(endpoint, "raised", error)

my_bot = MyBot(command_prefix = ">", intents = intents, chunk_guilds_at_startup = False)

@my_bot.ipc.route()
async def get_guild_ids(data):
    final = []
    for guild in my_bot.guilds:
        final.append(guild.id)
    return final # returns the guild ids to the client

my_bot.ipc.start()
my_bot.run(TOKEN)
```

> main.py

```
from discord.ext.commands.core import bot_has_permissions, bot_has_role
from quart import Quart, render_template, request, session, redirect, url_for
from quart_discord import DiscordOAuth2Session
from discord.ext import ipc

app = Quart(__name__)
ipc_client = ipc.Client(secret_key = IPC_SECRET_KEY)

app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = IPC_SECRET_KEY
app.config["DISCORD_CLIENT_ID"] = DISCORD_CLIENT_ID
app.config["DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET"] = DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET
app.config["DISCORD_REDIRECT_URI"] = DISCORD_REDIRECT_URI

discord = DiscordOAuth2Session(app)

@app.route("/dashboard")
async def dasboard():
    guild_ids = await ipc_client.request("get_guild_ids")
    return await render_template("list.html", guild_ids = guild_ids)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=5001)
```

> list.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    {% for guild_id in guild_ids %}
    <p>{{ guild_id }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Reaching out to: http://localhost:5001/dashboard gives me the list of guild ids the bot is joined.
As far as I understood, calling `await ipc_client.request("get_guild_ids")`, sends a websocket request `IPC Server <` with the answer received straight away `IPC Server >`:

```
DEBUG:discord.ext.ipc.server:IPC Server < {'endpoint': 'get_guild_ids', 'data': {}, 'headers': {'Authorization': 'SUPER-MEGA-SECRET-KEY'}}
DEBUG:discord.ext.ipc.server:IPC Server > [65465464465464, 9879879879879879]
```

### Now looking into Django

The `bot.py` from above is still running.
Under normal conditions, Django is running synchronous and you cannot come up with a `async def` function. So we have to switch to asynchronous with an import `from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync, sync_to_async`.
I'm using a `@login_required` decorator and according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64908222/error-your-view-return-an-httpresponse-object-it-returned-an-unawaited-corouti), I have to wrap the `@login_required` decorator into `@sync_to_async` and `@async_to_sync`, otherwise I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR: Your view return an HttpResponse object. It returned an unawaited coroutine instead. You may need to add an 'await' into your view
```

So what is the problem now?
The `First request` is working like a charme and I'm getting the result what I'm expecting. After a refresh of the webpage, I'm getting the error shown in the `Second request`. After refreshing a third time, the error changed another time, see: `Third request`.
What I'm guessing is, Django makes the request and closes the connection in an faulty way and does not reopen it after a refresh. After restarting the Django Server due to StatReloader, it's working again, once, till another restart and so on.

Do I have to use Channels/Consumers for this particular case or is there another way? If Channels is the "one and only" solution, how would I throw out a websocket request.
I'm just failing on the websocket connection to `bot.py` so I can send the command `{'endpoint': 'get_guild_ids', 'data': {}, 'headers': {'Authorisation': 'SUPER-MEGA-SECRET-KEY'}}` to interact with it.

### First request

> bot.py response

```
INFO:discord.ext.ipc.server:Initiating Multicast Server.
DEBUG:discord.ext.ipc.server:Multicast Server < {'connect': True, 'headers': {'Authorization': 'SUPER-MEGA-SECRET-KEY'}}
DEBUG:discord.ext.ipc.server:Multicast Server > {'message': 'Connection success', 'port': 8765, 'code': 200}
INFO:discord.ext.ipc.server:Initiating IPC Server.
DEBUG:discord.ext.ipc.server:IPC Server < {'endpoint': 'get_guild_ids', 'data': {}, 'headers': {'Authorization': 'SUPER-MEGA-SECRET-KEY'}}
DEBUG:discord.ext.ipc.server:IPC Server > [65465464465464, 9879879879879879]
```

> Django response

```
{"list": [65465464465464, 9879879879879879]}
```

### Second request

> bot.py response

```
DEBUG:discord.ext.ipc.server:IPC Server < {'endpoint': 'get_guild_ids', 'data': {}, 'headers': {'Authorization': 'SUPER-MEGA-SECRET-KEY'}}
DEBUG:discord.ext.ipc.server:IPC Server > [65465464465464, 9879879879879879]
```

> Django response:

```
Django Error: 
TypeError at /ipc/guild_count
the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not RuntimeError
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/ipc/guild_count
Django Version: 3.2.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not RuntimeError
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py, line 341, in loads
Python Executable:  /home/user/python/discord/django/mysite/.venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path:    
['/home/user/python/discord/django/mysite/mysite-website',
 '/usr/lib/python37.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/user/python/discord/django/mysite/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

### Third request

> bot.py response

`No IPC request and response traceable`

> Django response

```
Django Error:
ConnectionResetError at /ipc/guild_count
Cannot write to closing transport
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/ipc/guild_count
Django Version: 3.2.5
Exception Type: ConnectionResetError
Exception Value:    
Cannot write to closing transport
Exception Location: /home/user/python/discord/django/mysite/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/http_websocket.py, line 598, in _send_frame
Python Executable:  /home/user/python/discord/django/mysite/.venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path:    
['/home/user/python/discord/django/mysite/mysite-website',
 '/usr/lib/python37.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/user/python/discord/django/mysite/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
```

> views.py

```
from django.http import HttpRequest, JsonResponse
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from discord.ext import ipc
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync, sync_to_async

ipc_client = ipc.Client(secret_key = IPC_SECRET_KEY)
@sync_to_async
@login_required(login_url='/oauth2/login')
@async_to_sync
async def get_guild_count(request):
    guild_count = await ipc_client.request('get_guild_ids') 
    print(guild_count)
    return JsonResponse({"list": guild_count})
```

> urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('oauth2/login', views.discord_login, name='oauth2_login'),
    path('ipc/guild_count', views.get_guild_count, name='get_guild_count'),
]
```

## Update:

Here is some more debugging. At first we see a clean request with the correct reply coming back. After the first refresh, the RuntimeError occurs, due to the old task is still pending to be ended(?).

```
DEBUG:asyncio:Using selector: EpollSelector
DEBUG:asyncio:Using selector: EpollSelector
INFO:discord.ext.ipc.client:Requesting IPC Server for 'get_guild_ids' with {}
INFO:discord.ext.ipc.client:Initiating WebSocket connection.
INFO:discord.ext.ipc.client:Client connected to ws://localhost:8765
DEBUG:discord.ext.ipc.client:Client > {'endpoint': 'get_guild_ids', 'data': {}, 'headers': {'Authorization': 'SUPER-MEGA-SECRET-KEY'}}
DEBUG:discord.ext.ipc.client:Client < WSMessage(type=<WSMsgType.TEXT: 1>, data='[65465464465464, 9879879879879879]', extra='')
<class 'list'> [65465464465464, 9879879879879879]

"GET /ipc/guild_count HTTP/1.1" 200 49
DEBUG:asyncio:Using selector: EpollSelector
DEBUG:asyncio:Using selector: EpollSelector
INFO:discord.ext.ipc.client:Requesting IPC Server for 'get_guild_ids' with {}
DEBUG:discord.ext.ipc.client:Client > {'endpoint': 'get_guild_ids', 'data': {}, 'headers': {'Authorization': 'SUPER-MEGA-SECRET-KEY'}}
DEBUG:discord.ext.ipc.client:Client < WSMessage(type=<WSMsgType.ERROR: 258>, data=RuntimeError('Task <Task pending coro=<AsyncToSync.main_wrap() running at /home/aim/python/discord/django/ballern/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py:292> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at /usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py:158]> got Future attached to a different loop'), extra=None)
Internal Server Error: /ipc/guild_count
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
```