# The view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned an unawaited coroutine instead. You may need to add an 'await' into your view

Tags: django, asynchronous

Python: 3.8 Django: 3.2.

I am building a django app following this article([ERROR: Your view return an HttpResponse object. It returned an unawaited coroutine instead. You may need to add an 'await' into your view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64908222/error-your-view-return-an-httpresponse-object-it-returned-an-unawaited-corouti))

Here is my code:

```
import asyncio
```

This is the view

```
async def get_smokables():
    print("Getting smokeables...")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)

async def save_setting(request):
   await asyncio.gather(*[get_smokables()])
   return HttpResponse('ok')
```

Run command:

```
uvicorn config.asgi:application --reload
```

When I tried above code, it says "The view views.save_setting didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned an unawaited coroutine instead. You may need to add an 'await' into your view."

Comment: Did you solve this issue ?